# SQL Server MERGE with two Match outcomes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to create an archive (TGT) that contains the latest version of a rolling (SRC) table. SRC may contain multiple versions and duplicates, but TGT should only contain unique, latest rows.

There are 4 columns - A, B, C and D that form a UNIQUE key, and a 5th column, E that represents a version number.

So if I do a join on the following:

```
SRC.A = TGT.A AND SRC.B = TGT.B AND SRC.C = TGT.C AND SRC.D = TGT.D
```

There should be two outcomes - Match or no match. However, I have a sub-condition I want to apply if there is a match, so there's really 3 possible outcomes I'm looking for:

1. Match `AND SRC.E > TGT.E`  => SRC is a higher version, so TGT row should be updated
2. Match `AND SRC.E <= TGT.E`  => SRC is older or equal, so nothing should be done
3. No Match => SRC row should be inserted into TGT

The problem I run into is with outcomes 2 and 3, because `MERGE` only allows two `WHEN MATCHED` clauses, and in that case, one must be an `UPDATE` and the other must be a `DELETE`.  I really want an `UPDATE` and a "do nothing"

Something along these lines:

```
MERGE
    Target AS TGT
USING
    Source AS SRC ON SRC.A = TGT.A AND SRC.B = TGT.B AND SRC.C = TGT.C AND SRC.D = TGT.D

WHEN MATCHED AND SRC.E > TGT.E   -- SRC is newer, so update TGT
    THEN UPDATE SET TGT.E = SRC.E

WHEN MATCHED  -- "AND SRC.E <= TGT.E” is implied...
    -- SRC is older or equal, so do nothing

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET   -- SRC doesn't exist in TGT, so insert it
    THEN INSERT VALUES (SRC.A, SRC.B, SRC.C, SRC.D, SRC.E)
```

is this possible? Is it as simple as somehow rearranging my join?

I tried removing the second `WHEN MATCHED` clause, but then it causes a duplicate key warning because it tries to insert the older record

I'm using SQL Server 2016 if that changes anything

Comment: Whats the problem here? Just remove the "do nothing" `WHEN MATCHED` and done, it's not mandatory. Be careful if you have multiple rows with versions of `E` newer than target table for the same key.

Comment: Regular updates in SQL Server don't comply about matching against more than 1 row with the values to update (although the result isn't deterministic), but the merge's update somehow requires it. You can either filter your source table (with a CTE or subquery) to just consider the most updated version and compare against that one, or split your merge into update + insert as separate operations.

Comment: EzLo, I tried that first but I get a duplicate key violation. I assumed it was because the query was trying to insert the row where `SRC.E <= TGT.E`. However, your warning about "multiple rows with versions of `E` newer than target", I think that may be the issue I'm running into - because that would definitely occur. I assumed it would just keep updating the latest, but perhaps that can't be done in one query, and would instead have to be done iteratively - which would be too inefficient to consider. Can I do subquery for `SRC` that selects max `E` *and* filters duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate your source table as much as you want with a CTE or subquery, like the following example.

```
;WITH MostRecentSourceVersion AS
(
    SELECT
        S.A,
        S.B,
        S.C,
        S.D,
        E = MAX(S.E) -- Assuming the most recent is the MAX
    FROM
        Source AS S
    GROUP BY
        S.A, -- Your keys here
        S.B,
        S.C,
        S.D
)
MERGE
    Target AS TGT
USING
    MostRecentSourceVersion AS SRC
ON
    SRC.A=TGT.A AND SRC.B=TGT.B AND SRC.C=TGT.C AND SRC.D=TGT.D
WHEN MATCHED AND SRC.E > TGT.E   -- SRC is newer, so update TGT
    THEN UPDATE SET TGT.E = SRC.E
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET   -- SRC doesn't exist in TGT, so insert it
    THEN INSERT VALUES (SRC.A, SRC.B, SRC.C, SRC.D, SRC.E);
```

This way you can be sure that, if there is a match, it will always be 1.

You can also use `ROW_NUMBER()` if you need more than 1 column to determine the most recent version (will have to filter where row number = 1).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's appropriate to answer my own question, but I found a solution that *seems* to work (please correct me if you see a problem with it!) and thought I would share it for future visitors:

```
MERGE
    Target AS TGT
USING
    (
         SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
             A, B, C, D
         FROM
             Source
         ORDER BY
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B, C, D ORDER BY E DESC)
     ) AS SRC
ON
    SRC.A = TGT.A
    AND SRC.B = TGT.B
    AND SRC.C = TGT.C
    AND SRC.D = TGT.D
WHEN MATCHED AND SRC.E > TGT.E
    THEN UPDATE SET TGT.E = SRC.E
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT VALUES (SRC.A, SRC.B, SRC.C, SRC.D, SRC.E)
```